# Custom links with .htaccess file to access two parameters or more

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, xampp, custom-url

I am working on XAMPP V.3.2.1 on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

I have the following code in my **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /?cmd=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now, when i write link like

```
http://localhost/aboutUs
http://localhost/MyAnyOtherPage
```

it works fine even if i use form in the page with post back method, but when i try to use  links with two parameters and i change my **.htaccess** file link like this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /?cmd=$1&caseSno=$2 [NC,L]
```

In this way i am accessing my page by **cmd** and searching database record with **caseSno** parameters.

To achieve this how can i write my hard coded links to run my page with searching database tables and pitch records with second parameter **caseSno**?
This is not working for me:

My Original link is :

```
localhost/?cmd=caseDetailsByCaseSno&caseSno=2308
```

How to write this?
The following is not working for me?

```
http://localhost/caseInformation/case/234
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For the two parameters, what part of the clean URL should be in the rewrite/query string?

Comment: i want to use the page name in query string i don't want to display case number or anything else.

Comment: Please give an example of exactly how the URL is supposed to look like with two parameters.

Comment: I want to use URL like this: localhost/caseDetailsByCaseSno/234 which means that caseDetailsByCaseSno is the name of the page where 234 is the number i need to search within the databse table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you with two parameters.

If you have this URL `http://localhost/caseDetailsByCaseSno/234` then you should be able to use this htaccess.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?cmd=$1&caseSno=$2 [NC,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /?cmd=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: After changing my RewriteRule to yours, it does not work than

Comment: Please give an example of exactly how the URL is supposed to look like with two parameters.

Comment: I want to use URL like this: http://localhost/caseDetailsByCaseSno/234     which means that caseDetailsByCaseSno is the name of the page where 234 is the number i need to search within the databse table

Comment: It is working fine now but the problem is now that it is not displaying the .css file. should i need to change the css file path in the main template page. i.e. the existing link is = <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> how should i change the path of the css file here?

Comment: Use absolute paths or include the `/` with JS and CSS when doing rewrites so do this. `href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"` Notice I added a backslash in front of bootstrap.